# Identify soundtrack from Visa Europe Slovakian ad?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

Can someone please identify the song playing in the background of this Slovakian Visa ad [Nová kampaň spoločnosti Visa vyzýva k platbám kartou alebo mobilom aj pri malých nákupoch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JkxQBRXmjE)?

Comment: Sounds 1960s, but lyrics hard to catch.

Comment: @Angst The lyrics are not that hard to catch, but you have probably underwent the same frustration I did, when I was trying to find it by lyrics. Because google does not know the lyrics of this song.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually found it, it is "Running not walking" by "Don & The Goodtimes". And awesome guess on the period from Angst, it's really from the 60's.

Comment: glad you found it, cos I would like to hear the full song. any chance of adding a link to a YT video of it ?

Comment: @Angst if you put the name in youtube search, you find it easily, but in case it is blocked in your country for whatever reason, try this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq11bMk_ai0